# WPF: How do I set the property Helptext with C #

Tags: c#, wpf, accessibility

I am developing a text editor with WPF which should also be usable for blind people.

For screenreaders to read the program interface, the Helptext property must be set for components.

In XAML, this is how it works:

```
AutomationProperties.HelpText = "Here the accessibility of the editor can be activated or deactivated"
```

But how do I set the property HelpText in C#?

Comment: the code that you provided is written in c# syntax

Comment: No! Here is the whole Xaml-Line:  <CheckBox Name="ChkBarrierefrei" Content="Editor ba_rrierefrei" ToolTip="Hier kann die Barrierefreiheit des Editors aktiviert oder deaktiviert werden" AutomationProperties.HelpText="Hier kann die Barrierefreiheit des Editors aktiviert oder deaktiviert werden" Margin="10" Click="ChkBarrierefrei_CheckedChanged"/>

Comment: ok, see my answer according to your comment.

Comment: *Why* do you want to set the property in code-behind?

Comment: @Thomas Flinkow Because I have to set the property at runtime!

Comment: @MarkusLemcke Can you not use Bindings? As far as I know, you can bind to `AutomationProperties.HelpText` like e.g. `AutomationProperties.HelpText=“{Binding MyHelpText}”`.

Comment: @ Thomas Flinkow I dont know. I'm a beginner in matters of WPF. Could you please give me an example? Make it Please for this line: <CheckBox Name="ChkBarrierefrei" Content="Editor ba_rrierefrei" ToolTip="Hier kann die Barrierefreiheit des Editors aktiviert oder deaktiviert werden" AutomationProperties.HelpText="Hier kann die Barrierefreiheit des Editors aktiviert oder deaktiviert werden" Margin="10" Click="ChkBarrierefrei_CheckedChanged"/>

Comment: @MarkusLemcke sorry for the late reply. Please see my answer below, I tried to explain the Binding in the simplest possible way. I know it's a long answer and some parts may be difficult to understand, so please feel free to ask questions etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attached properties conventionally have a static method that is the property name prefixed with "Set" to update from code.  In this case
[SetHelpText(DependencyObject, value)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationproperties.sethelptext(v=vs.110).aspx)

`AutomationProperties.SetHelpText(ChkBarrierefrei, "Here the accessibility of the editor can be activated or deactivated")`

Answer (score 0):

As you've asked for an example on how to use bindings to achieve your goal, here is a simple one.

---

We first need to create a class that works as our base class for every so-called *ViewModel*.

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

We can now derive specific ViewModels from that class, namely the one we want to use to hold the BarriereFrei Help Text.

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string barriereFreiHelpText = "Here the accessibility of the editor can be activated or deactivated.";

    public string BarriereFreiHelpText
    {
        get { return this.barriereFreiHelpText; }
        set
        {
            if (value == this.barriereFreiHelpText)
            {
                return;
            }

            this.barriereFreiHelpText = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged(); // This line makes sure the UI is updated 
                                         // whenever a new help text is set.            
            }
    }
}
```

In the View (I assumed it's called `MainWindow`) we can now use the previously defined ViewModel like shown below:

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:MyProject.ViewModels">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewModel:MyViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <CheckBox x:Name="ChkBarrierefrei" 
                  Content="Editor ba_rrierefrei" 
                  ToolTip="Hier kann die Barrierefreiheit des Editors aktiviert oder deaktiviert werden" 
                  AutomationProperties.HelpText="{Binding BarriereFreiHelpText}"
                  Margin="10" 
                  Click="ChkBarrierefrei_CheckedChanged"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Did you notice the

> `AutomationProperties.HelpText="{Binding BarriereFreiHelpText}"`

part? This is where the magic happens. What this line does is it ensures that the `HelpText` property is always equal to what you set in the ViewModels `BarriereFreiHelpText` property.

---

To make this all work correctly, somewhere in your application you need to wire up the ViewModel and the Window like this:

```
MyViewModel viewModel = new MyViewModel();
MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
window.DataContext = viewModel;
```

and you can now change the help text at runtime using

```
(window.DataContext as MyViewModel).BarriereFreiHelpText = "Whatever you want it to be";
```

and the UI is automatically updated with the new help text.

---

This is definitely a better solution than setting the `CheckBox`es `AutomationProperties.HelpText` property directly, as it is `much cleaner` and `less tightly coupled` (you are changing the property of a ViewModel without knowing about any UI).

I understand that this all might be overwhelming, but I strongly recommend you follow the so-called MVVM approach, not only for the `CheckBox`es help text, but for everything at all. You will save yourself much time, lines of code and nasty bugs.

---

Further reading:

- [MVVM und WPF](http://www.codingfreaks.de/2016/03/28/wpf-und-mvvm-richtig-einsetzen-teil-1/) (german) explains how to use MVVM and is way more detailed and easier to understand than my answer,
- [The World's Simplest C# WPF MVVM Example](https://www.markwithall.com/programming/2013/03/01/worlds-simplest-csharp-wpf-mvvm-example.html) is a very nice, short and comprehendible article covering everything you need to know in order to create robust and reusable WPF applications,
- [MVVM Step by Step from Basic to Advanced](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/819294/WPF-MVVM-step-by-step-Basics-to-Advance-Level) another nice article, covering *why* MVVM makes sense.

---

I hope it's not to late to go with the MVVM approach, and I wish you lots of success and fun with MVVM - it really is nice and fun once you got a hang of it, believe me ;)